# Pandas - dtype shows int, but describe shows float

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, integer

I have changed my variable `age` to an integer since it was stored as a float:

```
sessions['age'] = sessions['age'].astype(int)
```

Pandas `dtypes` returns an int:

```
In: sessions['age'].dtype
Out: dtype('int64')
```

However, `describe()` shows a float:

```
In: sessions['age'].describe()
Out: Name: age, dtype: float64
```

Trying to plot the variable shows the following error message:

```
ax = sns.distplot(sessions["age"])
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

It looks like my variable is not an integer. What is going wrong?